# Waterline - Mix of AND & OR

Tags: sails.js, waterline

[using-mix-of-and-and-or-clause-in-sails-and-waterline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120258/using-mix-of-and-and-or-clause-in-sails-and-waterline)

[use-and-in-waterline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610172/use-and-in-waterline?rq=1)

Both of this question, deal with having n fields in the or,  but unique fields in the AND, which is just implicitly added when to place attribute names, those are converted to ANDS, like this:

```
{attribute1: 'valueToMatch', or: [{attribute2: {contains: 'someWord'}}, {attribute3: {contains: 'someWord'}}]
```

Which is fine if the AND (attribute1) is only used once, but if you want 2 or more conditions that are met (AND) and those have optional conditions inside (OR) this doesn't help

Is there a way around?

Lets say i have a user model likes this

```
let User = {
  attributes:{
    firstName: {type: 'string'},
    lastName:  {type: 'string'}
  }
};
```

And that i want to be able to search if certain string is at least in one of those fields (OR), lets say i pass a string that could be either the first name or the lastname, that can be accomplished using the or syntax

```
let searchString = 'John'
let results = yield User.find({or: [
   {firstName: {contains: searchString}]},
   {lastName: {contains: searchString}]}
});
```

So far so good, but if my search string contains more words, lets say

```
let searchString = 'John Doe'
```

It won't work unless there is a record with a firstName or lastName that contains the complete string.

I know there are a few hacky workarouds, like having a fullName attribute that can be generated on create & update based on the other ones and search for that, but since i'm duplicating data and this way i won't be able to search with lastName before the firstName, is not a perfect solution. Also i could split the searchString and add eachword to the OR array, and somehow is better, but my results won't be filtered enough, let alone ranked, so its not a perfect solution either, and lastly i could do a raw query....

So the real question is how to do an AND in waterline that can be used with an or to further refine, since to me an AND is generated based on the attribute name criteria passed.

Is there something like this?

```
// Lets assume i've splitted the searchString
let string1 = 'John';
let string2 = 'Doe'
let results = yield User.find({
  and: [
   {or: [
       {firstName: {contains: string1}},
       {lastName: {contains: string1}}
     ]
   },
   {or: [
      {firstName: {contains: string2}},
      {lastName: {contains: string2}}
    ]
   },
  ]
});
```

Or what option do i have here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow the answer was pretty obvious (just not to me at first), for some reason i thought you could only add one attribute/property to the the objects added to the or array, but then i realized nobody ever said that, so i just had to add another property and combine.

Following the same example on the question, it could be like this:

```
// Lets assume i've splitted the searchString
let string1 = 'John';
let string2 = 'Doe'
let results = yield User.find({or: [
       {firstName: {contains: string1}, lastName: {contains: string2}},
       {lastName: {contains: string1}, {firstName: {contains: string2}}
     ]
});
```

That's it, no need for explicit AND

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation where I really needed to have something like:

```
var whereCondition = {
    //...
    and: [
        { or: [...]},
        { or: [...]}
    ]
    //...
}
```

The solution was to nest or conditions within themselves:

```
var where = {
    or: [
        { 
            name: 'Jim',
            or: [
                { 
                    age: 30
                },
                { 
                    age: 31
                },
            ]
        },
        { 
            name: 'Joe',
            or: [
                { 
                    age: 30
                },
                { 
                    age: 31
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

After a bit of cleanup:

```
var where = {
    or: [
        { 
            name: 'Jim'
        },
        { 
            name: 'Joe'
        },
    ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < where.or.length; i++) {
    where.or[i].or = [
                { 
                    age: 30
                },
                { 
                    age: 31
                },
            ];
}
```

Looks a bit ugly, I would have preferred the usage of a `and` condition, but after to much time spent on this, it's a case of "whatever works"